# string as second argument in url dispatcher for CBV

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

Before class based views my `urls.py` looked like that:

```
urlpatterns= patterns('mypackage.views',
                      url(r'^$', 'home', name='home'),
                      url(r'other', name='other'),
                      )
```

Now my home view is class based. As i like uniformity, I do **not** would like to keep the view class as string. I tried:

```
urlpatterns= patterns('mypackage.views',
                      url(r'^$', 'Home.as_view', name='home'),
                      url(r'Other.as_view', name='other'),
                      )
```

and I get `Parent module mypackage.views.Home does not exist` . If I simply give the class name like:

```
urlpatterns= patterns('mypackage.views',
                      url(r'^$', 'Home', name='home'),
                      url(r'Other', name='other'),
                      )
```

I get: `__init__ takes exactly 1 argument, 2 given`

Is there a way to pass a string as second argument to the `url` function for CBV as for FBV instead of `from mypackage.views import *` ?

**EDIT**:
There seems to be no built-in solution for this. In this case: why are strings as second parameter allowed for the url function: Doesn't it violate the zen ("there is only one way to do this)?

Answer (score 2):

You should import the class-based view and specify them that way:

```
from mypackage.views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('mypackage.views',
                       url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home'),
                       url(r'other', Other.as_view() name='other'),
                       )
```

Also note that your `url()` calls should have three parameters: the URL pattern, the view and name (some examples you wrote don't have all of these).

Comment: This is what I am trying to figure out, why is there the possibility to pass a string as second parameter, if it does only work with FBV?

Comment: @ProfHase85 that's for historical reasons (i.e., FBVs). CBVs are done by importing the view objects and calling `as_view()`.

Comment: FWIW, "import *" statements are the devil. "from mypackage.views import Home, Other"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass your view as string, then in your views do this:

```
class Home(View):
    pass

home = Home.as_view()
```

then in your url:

```
url(r'^$', 'mypackage.views.home', name='home'),
```

You need to use full path.

Comment: Thanks, this is a possible solution, but this one violates the DRY principle, as one has to write the same stuff for every view